# how to deploy windows azure ServiceDefinition.csdef file

Tags: azure, deployment

I have a static website that I'm hosting on an azure web site. I have the need to run an elevated startup task and I believe the way to do this is via a ServiceDefinition.csdef file.

The problem is, I can't figure out how to get azure to run my command when I don't have a visual studio project. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Web Sites don't use the `ServiceDefinition.csdef`, nor do they allow for any type of elevated startup tasks. For that, you'll need to shift to Cloud Services and use a Web Role. And for that, you'll either need to create a Visual Studio project, or use PowerShell to create it independently, without worrying about Visual Studio (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17177162/272109) I posted with the relevant PowerShell cmdlets for setting up a project independent of Visual Studio).